# Conversion to float in uint32_t calculation

Tags: c, casting, arithmetic-expressions, int32, uint32

I am trying to improve a SWRTC by modifying the definition of a second (**long unsigned n_ticks_per_second**) by synchronizing time with a server.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){

    int32_t total_drift_SEC;
    int32_t drift_per_sec_TICK;
    uint32_t at_update_posix_time = 1491265740;
    uint32_t posix_time = 1491265680;
    uint32_t last_update_posix_time = 1491251330;
    long unsigned n_ticks_per_sec = 1000;

    total_drift_SEC = (posix_time - at_update_posix_time);
    drift_per_sec_TICK = ((float) total_drift_SEC) / (at_update_posix_time - last_update_posix_time);

    n_ticks_per_sec += drift_per_sec_TICK;

    printf("Total drift sec %d\r\n", total_drift_SEC);
    printf("Drift per sec in ticks %d\r\n", drift_per_sec_TICK);
    printf("n_ticks_per_second %lu\r\n", n_ticks_per_sec);

    return 0;

}
```

What I don't understand is that I need to cast **total_drift_SEC** to **float** in order to have a correct result in the end, *ie to have n_ticks_per_sec equal to 1000 in the end*.

The output of this code is:

> Total drift sec -60
>
> Drift per sec in ticks 0
>
> n_ticks_per_second 1000

Whereas the output of the code without the cast to float is:

> Total drift sec -60
>
> Drift per sec in ticks 298054
>
> n_ticks_per_second 299054

Comment: Alternative: `rift_per_sec_TICK = (1LL* total_drift_SEC) / (at_update_posix_time - last_update_posix_time);`

Comment: @chux: Or: ... `(int64_t) total_drift_SEC ...` simply something signed with higher rank then `uint32_t`.

Comment: @alk I prefer `1LL*` or similar versus casting as `1LL*` will not narrow `total_drift_SEC`, regardless of type, yet casting may narrow in a later version of code when `total_drift_SEC` is some type like `double`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line

```
drift_per_sec_TICK = total_drift_SEC / (at_update_posix_time - last_update_posix_time);
```

divides a 32 bit `signed int` by a 32 bit `unsigned int`.

32 bit `unsigned int` has a higher rank then 32 bit `signed int`.

When doing arithmetic operations the "*Usual Arithmetic Conversions*" are applied:

From the [C11 Standard (draft) 6.3.1.8/1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.8p1):

> if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank greater or
>   equal to the rank of the type of the other operand, then the operand with
>   signed integer type is converted to the type of the operand with unsigned
>   integer type.

So `-60` gets converted to a (32 bit) `unsigned int`: `4294967236`

Here

```
drift_per_sec_TICK = (float) total_drift_SEC / (at_update_posix_time - last_update_posix_time);
```

The following applies (from the paragraph of the C Standard as above):

> if the corresponding real type of either operand is float, the other
>   operand is converted, without change of type domain, to a type whose
>   corresponding real type is `float`.

---

To not blindly step into those traps always specify `-Wconversion` when compiling with GCC.

Answer (score 0):

Because with "integer" version `total_drift_SEC` will become `unsigned` so `-60` --> `4294967236`

```
4294967236 / 14410 = 298054
```

Using float the division will calculate:

```
-60/14410 = 0
```

Referring to the [c-standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) at page 53

> **6.3.1.8 Usual arithmetic conversions**
>
> 1 Many operators that expect operands of arithmetic type cause conversions and yield result
>   types in a similar way. The purpose is to determine a common real type for the operands
>   and result. For the specified operands, each operand is converted, without change of type
>   domain, to a type whose corresponding real type is the common real type. Unless
>   explicitly stated otherwise, the common real type is also the corresponding real type of
>   the result, whose type domain is the type domain of the operands if they are the same,
>   and complex otherwise. This pattern is called the usual arithmetic conversions:
>   [...]
>   Otherwise, the integer promotions are performed on both operands. Then the
>   following rules are applied to the promoted operands:
>
> - If both operands have the same type, then no further conversion is
>     needed. Otherwise, if both operands have signed integer types or both
>     have unsigned integer types, the operand with the type of lesser
>     integer conversion rank is converted to the type of the operand with
>     greater rank.
> - **Otherwise, if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank
>     greater or equal to the rank of the type of the other operand, then
>     the operand with signed integer type is converted to the type of the
>     operand with unsigned integer type.**
> - Otherwise, if the type of the operand with signed integer type can
>     represent all of the values of the type of the operand with unsigned
>     integer type, then the operand with unsigned integer type is
>     converted to the type of the operand with signed integer type.
> - Otherwise, both operands are converted to the unsigned integer type
>     corresponding to the type of the operand with signed integer type.

<sup>Ephasis mine</sup>

Comment: Thank you for the answer :)